# Why is there an extra type field in Sparkplug metric?

Tags: protocol-buffers, mqtt, mqtt-sparkplug

In `Sparkplug B` the metric used to publish measurement values from a device is defined in protbuf as follows:

```
 message Metric {

    string   name          = 1;        // Metric name - should only be included on birth
    uint64   alias         = 2;        // Metric alias - tied to name on birth and included in all later DATA messages
    uint64   timestamp     = 3;        // Timestamp associated with data acquisition time
    uint32   datatype      = 4;        // DataType of the metric/tag value
    bool     is_historical = 5;        // If this is historical data and should not update real time tag
    bool     is_transient  = 6;        // Tells consuming clients such as MQTT Engine to not store this as a tag
    bool     is_null       = 7;        // If this is null - explicitly say so rather than using -1, false, etc for some datatypes.
    MetaData metadata      = 8;        // Metadata for the payload
    PropertySet properties = 9;

    oneof value {
        uint32   int_value                      = 10;
        uint64   long_value                     = 11;
        float    float_value                    = 12;
        double   double_value                   = 13;
        bool     boolean_value                  = 14;
        string   string_value                   = 15;
        bytes    bytes_value                    = 16;       // Bytes, File
        DataSet  dataset_value                  = 17;
        Template template_value                 = 18;
        MetricValueExtension extension_value    = 19;
    }
    message MetricValueExtension {
        repeated google.protobuf.Any details = 1;
    }
}
```

**First Question:**

I used to work with Protobuf/GRPC a bit in the past and wonder, why the datatype is specified as an extra identifier `uint32   datatype`. In the `oneof` section the different possible types are defines anyway, why is there a need for an extra setting, because the type is automatically available from the types within the `oneof` ? In my previous work I never had to specify the type as an extra field.

To put an example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message exampleMessage
{
  string exampleString = 1;
  bytes exampleBytes = 2;
  uint32 exampleInt = 3;
  repeated uint32 repeatedInt = 4;
  oneof value {
            uint32   int_value                      = 5;
            string   text_value                     = 6;
            }
  };
```

A message based on that proto could be (in json):

```
{
  "repeatedInt": [
    2,
    4
  ],
  "exampleString": "",
  "exampleBytes": [],
  "exampleInt": 2,
  "text_value": "Hi there"
}
```

In this case I do not specify the particular type of `text_value`.

**Second Question:**

Is the above protobuf definition used normally *as it is* or is it expected to be extended, so that more complex data types (structured data) can be used additionally when necessary? For Instance one could group together the phase voltages for L1, L2 and L3 in a joint message "voltages", containing three voltage values.

Hope my questions are clear enough.